# wc_price($price) not showing the discount by FILTER "woocommerce_product_get_regular_price"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, price

With WooCommerce, I have the following function that allow me to make a discount on my products prices:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_price' , 99, 2 );
function custom_price( $price, $product )
{
$price = $price - 2;
return $price
}
```

This is working everywhere *(in the shop, in the cart, in the backend)*, but not in my custom product list plugin:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_nybeorderlist_endpoint', 'patrickorderlist_my_account_endpoint_content' );
function patrickorderlist_my_account_endpoint_content() {

    //All WP_Query

    echo wc_price($price);
}
```

This shows the regular price without the discount. Both pieces of code are in the same plugin.

Comment: add priority 100 to your custom plugin

Comment: Do you mean changing the "add_filter" priority? I tried changing it from 99 to 100 and to 1. This does not help. Keep in mind that the code for the product list and "add_filter" function are in the same plugin. I also tried to lower the add_action then the add_filter and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For info, `wc_price()` is just a formatting function used to format prices and has nothing to do with the `$price` itself main argument. Your problem is that in your 2nd function, the variable `$price` certainly doesn't use the `WC_Product` method `get_regular_price()`, which is required in your case… So in your WP_Query loop, you need to get the WC_Product object instance, then from this object get the price using the method `get_regular_price()`…

So try something like *(it's an example as you don't provide your `WP_Query` in your question)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_nybeorderlist_endpoint', 'rm_orderlist_my_account_endpoint_content' );
function rm_orderlist_my_account_endpoint_content() {

    $products = new WP_Query( $args ); // $args variable is your arguments array for this query

    if ( $products->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();

    // Get the WC_Product Object instance
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );

    // Get the regular price from the WC_Product Object
    $price   = $product->get_regular_price();

    // Output the product formatted price
    echo wc_price($price);

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

Now it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks... $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
 $price   = $product->get_regular_price()
This was the solution. Mark thread as solved.

Comment: @Redman I have edited my code a bit as there was some mistakes… But yes `$product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );` and `$price = $product->get_regular_price();` is the right way…